# Blank page when website is hosted online

Tags: php, host, filezilla

I have build a small website with some php. It works perfectly on my localhost (even without database information it loads the html and css).

However when I put it online I just get a blankpage, no errors, nothing. However when I manually type a page it redirects to the login page (which is good).

Anyone experienced this before?

Thanks
EDIT2: After some debugging advice I got this error

> Warning: include_once(classes/users.class.php): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in
>   /customers/c/2/9/nicolasdecroos.be/httpd.www/eindwerk/login.php on
>   line 8 Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   'classes/users.class.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
>   /customers/c/2/9/nicolasdecroos.be/httpd.www/eindwerk/login.php on
>   line 8 Fatal error: Class 'user' not found in
>   /customers/c/2/9/nicolasdecroos.be/httpd.www/eindwerk/login.php on
>   line 9

Edit: Here is the PHP code on the login page

```
<?php
session_start();
    include_once("classes/users.class.php");
    $user = new user();

    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
    {
        header('location: index.php');
    }
    else
    {
        if(!empty($_POST))
        {
            try
            {
                $user->login($_POST['studentennummer'],$_POST['password']);
            }
            catch (Exception $error)
            {
                $message = $error->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

This is users.class

*Sorry if it's to much code, I'm not sure which part would be the most interesting.

```
<?php
    include_once("classes/db.class.php");

    class user
    {
         private $m_sStudentennummer;
         private $m_sPassword;
         private $m_sStatus;



         public function __get($p_sProperty)
         {
            switch ($p_sProperty) 
            {
                case 'Studentennummer':
                    return $this->m_sStudentennummer;
                    break;

                case 'Password':
                    return $this->m_sPassword;
                    break;

                case 'Status':
                    return $this->m_sStatus;
                    break;

            }
         }

         public function __set($p_sProperty, $p_vValue)
         {
            switch ($p_sProperty) 
            {
                case 'Studentennummer':
                    $this->m_sStudentennummer = $p_vValue;
                    break;

                case 'Password':
                    $this->m_sPassword = $p_vValue;
                    break;

                case 'Status':
                    $this->m_sStatus = $p_vValue;
                    break;

            }
         }

         public function userCheck($p_sInput)
         {
            $db = new db();

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_id = '". $p_sInput . "'";

            $result = $db->conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows == 0) 
            {
                return "true";
            }
            else
            {
                return "false";
            }
         }

         public function login($p_sStudentennummer, $p_sPassword)
         {
            $db = new db();

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_nr = '".$db->conn->real_escape_string($p_sStudentennummer)."' AND u_pass = '".$db->conn->real_escape_string($p_sPassword)."';";

            $result = $db->conn->query($sql);

            $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();

             $status = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_nr = '".$db->conn->real_escape_string($p_sStudentennummer)."' AND u_pass = '".$db->conn->real_escape_string($p_sPassword)."' AND u_group = 'student'";

             $statusRes = $db->conn->query($status);

            if ($result->num_rows == 1)
            {
                if ($statusRes->num_rows == 1)
                {
                $_SESSION['u_id'] = $rows['u_id'];
                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
                header('Location: index.php');
                }
                else
                {        
                $_SESSION['u_id'] = $rows['u_id'];
                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
                header('Location: my_events.php');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Username and/or password are invalid.");
            }
         }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Could be a number of things. Check the console and see if your request is valid.

Comment: Well, always the first step in such cases: what does the http servers log file say?

Comment: Some code would be nice.

Comment: trt to use error reporting or if your server have any file with some debug mode setting then on that setting.

Comment: Same PHP version? Need to see code for any idea as to what could be wrong.. Are all pages failing?

Comment: @chris85 no, it only seems to affect the login page atm

Comment: Okay so please post that code. Also if there is a difference in version numbers that would be useful.

Comment: @chris85 versions should be the same afaik, anyway to check?

Comment: Yes, http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php should give you the information.  There is nothing being reported in the logs?

Comment: @chris85 ok, the version is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright,

It was something dumb but I'll post it incase someone has troubles with this.

The map was called "**C**lasses". in the code it was written as "**c**lasses".

On localhost it wasn't a problem, but when you put it online it is.

Answer (score 0):

Change the error level for the online hosting if you can.
It will display every errors on the screen, but is very useful (for me at least).

```
<? error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>
```

Comment: Need display errors on was well to display them. `error_reporting(-1); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);` http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info Also this isn't an answer but a debugging comment.

Comment: @chris85 I got this error Warning: include_once(classes/users.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /customers/c/2/9/nicolasdecroos.be/httpd.www/eindwerk/login.php on line 8 Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'classes/users.class.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /customers/c/2/9/nicolasdecroos.be/httpd.www/eindwerk/login.php on line 8 Fatal error: Class 'user' not found in /customers/c/2/9/nicolasdecroos.be/httpd.www/eindwerk/login.php on line 9

Comment: Please update your question with the additional information. This seems pretty clear about the issue. Either the files aren't there or the PHP executing user doesn't have permissions.